# How do I get app ID and secret key when there are no options for this on admin page?

Tags: facebook

I have a third party facebook plugin that I am trying to use on my wordpress site. It is asking for a an App ID and secret key. I cannot find how or where to get this on facebook. I have searched the developers section on FB and found nothing. Tutorials I have found seem to be dated as it looks like FB has moved some things around. I see that I am supposed to register my app bu there are no options for this on my page. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Top right of the page is the "Create app" button. After you create an app, select it on the left hand side and there should be a "settings" section that contains your app_id and secret visible in the main part of the page

Comment: Thank you, but that what I'm having trouble with, there is no Create app button on the page. There is settings and logout and then ads manager button.

Comment: Have you actually registered as a developer?

Comment: I have not, how do I go about that?